# SPRING MVC - Use an external file as @PropertySource

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, properties-file

I was wondering how to use an external file to load some properties for my app in different contexts..

I know I can pass a file in `PropertySource` annotation. The problem is the path of the file.

I mean, it looks like it want a full path to the file, but different environments have different paths for `Tomcat` directory.

**My question is:**
Where is the correct directory to store this files (it must be outside to the app dir otherwise on every deploy it is deleted) and how I can link it in my application.

For instance, now i created a `/config` directory inside the `/webapps` directory of tomcat.

**From my Mac i can load the file in this way:**

```
@PropertySource("file:/Library/Tomcat/webapps/config/db.properties" )
```

but my production application is on a Linux server and obviously the path is different...

Any idea or, better, a best practice ti manage it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem to solve some time back, what we did was that we provided the **external directory path to properties file at time of server boot up**, as follows:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySources;

@Configuration
@PropertySources({@PropertySource("${ext.properties.dir:classpath:}/db.properties") })
public class ApplicationConfig {

}
```

**For XML based configuration:**

```
<context:property-placeholder
        location="${ext.properties.dir:classpath:}/db.properties" order="-1"
        ignore-unresolvable="true" ignore-resource-not-found="true" />
```

And supplied `ext.properties.dir` value from `application-server/jvm` as per environment:

**For instance, for DEV:**

```
-Dext.properties.dir=file:/dev/Library/Tomcat/webapps/config/
```

**and for PROD:**

```
-Dext.properties.dir=file:/prod/Library/Tomcat/webapps/config/
```